# html + css not rendering properly in android phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am developing the android apps in phonegap but in that my html not showing properly on android phone. problem is that i have four div's first div showing the canvas which is width and heigh is 100% , second div showing the header 
and third div showing the text data which is coming from server and last is div is for contact form but what happen if content of the third div is increases then it showing content from the middle but i want to show the page from top. please see the below image. 
following is the my html and css which is working properly on browser but not working properly on real device and i am also uploading screen shot. Please help me find out this bug.

html

```
 <div id="page">
    <div id="wrapper" style="display: none">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="designtech-left back"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="backToFirstPage" class="back_button" >Back</a>
            </div>
            <div class="designtech-left"><h3 style=" font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">Coures Detail</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="designtech-clear"></div>

        <div class="course_info_div" id="courseInfo">
            //dynamic content name , branch, duration and desc
                <p class="pclass">Course name : <span> Catia & 3D Max</span> </p> 
            <p class="pclass">Branch name :<span> Pune</span> </p>
            <p class="pclass">course duration :<span> 6 Months</span> </p>
            <p class="pclass">Description : <span> Details</span> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="designtech-clear"></div>
        <div class="contact">      

            <form id="contact-form"  method="post">
                <h3>Enquiry form</h3>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span>Name: (required)</span>
                        <input placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" id="name"  >
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span>Email: (required)</span>
                        <input placeholder="Please enter your email address" type="email" id="email-id"  >
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span>Telephone: (required)</span>
                        <input placeholder="Please enter your number" type="tel" id="contact"  >
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <span>Message: (required)</span>
                        <textarea placeholder="Include all the details you can" id="enquiry" ></textarea>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="center">
                    <button name="enquiry-form" type="button" id="enquiry-form">Submit</button>
                    <img src="res/drawable-mdpi/gif-load-medium.gif" id="email-progress" style="display: none;"/>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#page{ 
width:100%!important; 
height:100%; 
background-color:#ffffff;
text-align: left;
margin: 0pt auto;
padding: 0 0px;
position: relative;
}
#wrapper{ width:100%;}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:45px;
    color: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background: rgb(255,5,5); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,5,5,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 69%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,5,5,1)), color-stop(69%,rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(109,0,25,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,5,5,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 69%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,5,5,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 69%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,5,5,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 69%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,5,5,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 69%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0505', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.course_info_div
{
    position:relative;
    top:45px;
    background:#BCB9B9;
    padding: 12px 10px 20px 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font:16px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.course_info_div p.pclass{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.contact{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;

}

#contact-form {
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    background:#F9F9F9;
    padding: 10px 30px 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

below image showing the two views. left side view which is I want and right side view is on real device and emulator.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you're closing your .contact DIV. That might be causing an issue.

Comment: I did close the contact div but not commented properly.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon if this is way off but have you tried calling an location.href to an anchor point on the page after the server data has been received? I'm curious if that would work. So something like:

HTML:

```
<div id="courseInfo">
   <a name="courseInfo"></a>
   <p class="pclass">Course name : <span>
   <!-- ...etc -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function refreshUIAfterServerData(){
    document.location.href = 'index.html#courseInfoAnchor';
}
```

Clearly this doesn't get to why the issue is occurring - but honestly after dealing w/Android PhoneGap stuff myself for a while now - I've given up asking why on many things and just do what I have to to get in and out fast as I can!